# Accessing ArrayList<Mat> across Activities, OpenCV, Android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to use an ArrayList() across two different Activities. It is declared:

```
public static ArrayList<Mat> Video = new ArrayList<Mat>();
```

I read in frames from the camera and when I have 50 I go to my next activity.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    Mat frame = inputFrame.rgba();

    if(Video.size() < 50)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Added frame");
        Video.add(frame);
    }
    else
    {           
        String e = Integer.toString(Video.get(1).cols());
        Log.v(TAG1, e);
        e = Integer.toString(Video.get(1).rows());
        Log.v(TAG1, e);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Analysis.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return inputFrame.rgba();

}
```

The log output for this method is:

```
11-15 22:53:30.225: V/Values(32362): 800
11-15 22:53:30.225: V/Values(32362): 480
```

This is the correct height and width for the device this is running on(Galaxy S2).

Then in my next activities onCreate() I directly access "Video":

```
String e = Integer.toString(HomeScreen.Video.get(1).cols());
Log.v(TAG, e);
String h = Integer.toString(HomeScreen.Video.get(1).rows());
Log.v(TAG, h);
```

But this time the log reads:

```
11-15 22:53:30.840: V/Values2:(32362): 800
11-15 22:53:30.840: V/Values2:(32362): 0
```

So my question is, why is the row() value not 480 in both Logs? I need a List of frames because I am recording all the frames and then in another Activity I am going to operate on them and output the display(which I need to number of rows for).

Comment: I think there is no problem with the ArrayList. But may be with the class `Mat`.

Comment: For the life of my a cant find out what the problem here is. It seems from what I've tried that accessing Mat() across classes results in the rows() being set to 0, for no obvious reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the line:

```
Video.add(frame);
```

With

```
Video.add(frame.clone());
```

and it works perfectly!

I think in the top line i was only copying the header part of the frame and not the entire frame's contents.